# Custom youtube thumnail size

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm getting the thumbnail videos from youtube using the image subdomain practically you can get 5 images sizes like:

```
"http://img.youtube.com/vi/{videoId}/default.jpg"; // Small Default
 "http://img.youtube.com/vi/{videoId}/0.jpg"; // Large Default
 "http://img.youtube.com/vi/{videoId}/1.jpg";
 "http://img.youtube.com/vi/{videoId}/2.jpg";
 "http://img.youtube.com/vi/{videoId}/3.jpg";
```

I'm wondering if there's a different way to get other sizes for the thumbnails beside the defaults

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20542029/2274530

Comment: the answer is no it doesn't! the sizes are fixed!